# Can paper tape be used with any type of plaster?

Tags: drywall, plaster, tape

I'm preparing to plaster over a new plasterboard wall (drywall).  I plan to paper-tape the joints between plasterboard panels before the first coat of plaster.  (Some tapered joints and some joints where tapered meets butt)

I have 40-minute quick-set and Thistle multi-finish plaster (both come in bags / need mixing).  Can I use either to apply the paper tape or are there reasons to avoid one type of plaster?

Comment: tape should generally be used with joint compound,  the "40-minute quick-set" might be a joint compound, I can't tell from here. the Thistle multi is definately not.

Comment: Do you mean mudding/jointing the drywall seams for a flat finish?  Or plastering over all of the wall surface ?

Comment: @Criggie I mean plastering the entire wall surface

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen anyone plaster over drywall. If you are going to plaster you should be using "lath" not drywall.

Comment: A skim coat over the entire drywall surface is very common for critical lighting applications and/or when glossy paints will be used. Research Level-5 finish...

Comment: It's called Veneer plaster, it's actually the best finish you can get on sheetrock, because it won't ding or get damaged nearly as easy as drywall and paint alone.

Answer (score 1):

> "Can I use either (40-minute quick-set... Thistle multi-finish plaster) to apply the paper tape?"

You should use Joint Compound to set and initially cover the tape. Joint Compound has adhesive that facilitates a good bond. Look at the instructions on the two different materials and see if they are listed as joint compounds or if they mention use for bedding tape for joints.

> are there reasons to avoid one type of plaster?

Yes; "setting" type plasters (e.g. "40-minute quick-set") are difficult to work with because of their fast setting time and are not the best choice for novice plasterers. It will likely be better to work with a plaster that takes longer to set up to give you more working time.

NOTE- I use premix Joint Compound for tape joints and skimming. Yes it makes the job take multiple days and yes it is easy to work smooth and the long working time is exactly what I want and need.

[image]

Comment: @ Jimmy fix it: You can learn something new every day. So now I have learned a great lesson and something new: THANKS